# How can I replace symbol with char array in the given text

Tags: c++, char

I have text. For example : "Hello, whats your name?"  and I need to do this: "  Hello comma whats your name question mark"

I need change symbols with words using char arrays (not string class), What should I do, give me recommendations please.

Comment: What do you have so far and what problem are you encountering?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read this: [ask].

Comment: *I need change symbols with words using char arrays (not string class),* -- Arrays cannot be resized, so how are you to accomplish making the string "bigger"?  The `std::string` is dynamic, so it can be resized.

Comment: The question is way too broad. Google "c replace text string".

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, and we will be happy to help.

Comment: Anyway the best recommendation is: "use std::string`. Not using it is a poor idea. Tell us why you don't want to use the std::string class.

Comment: This question cannot be answered until you specify how this new string is to be created from an existing string if you can't use `std::string`.  Do you start out with one giant char array with enough space to insert extra characters?  Do you dynamically allocate the new string, fill it in, and return a pointer to it?  Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the string into a new buffer. I struggled a bit to get this working. I don't know whether it is what you wanted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k;
    size_t count_comma = 0;
    size_t count_question_mark = 0;
    char question_mark[] = "question mark";
    char comma[] = "comma";
    char *str;
    size_t str_size;
    char msg[] = "Hello, whats your name?";
    size_t msg_size = strlen(msg) + 1;

    for (i = 0; i < msg_size; i++) 
        if (msg[i] == ',') 
            count_comma++;
        else if (msg[i] == '?')
            count_question_mark++;

    str_size = msg_size + 1 
        //- count_comma - count_question_mark 
        + count_comma * strlen(comma) 
        + count_question_mark * strlen(question_mark);

    str = malloc(str_size);

    for (j = 0, i = 0; i < msg_size; i++) {
        if (msg[i] == ',') {
            str[j++] = ' ';
            i++;
            for (k = 0;  k < strlen(comma); k++) {
                str[j++] = comma[k];
            }
        } 
        if (msg[i] == '?') {
            str[j++] = ' ';
            i++;
            for (k = 0; k < strlen(question_mark); k++) {
                str[j++] = question_mark[k];
            }
        }

        str[j++] = msg[i];
    }

    str[j] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", msg);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program is valid C, but not valid C++, which the question is asking about. You need to cast the result of `malloc` explicitly to the correct pointer type in C++ and shouldn't use `malloc` and `printf` at all. Instead it should be `new` and `cout <<`. Of couse, in C++, one would not use `strlen` and C-style strings either, but `std::string` and its methods instead. That last one is ok I suppose, because OP gave it as a requirement *not* to use `std::string`. Still they did not say that they want to code in C.